# Spacy: nlp over tokens to annotate IOB file

Tags: python-3.x, named-entity-recognition, evaluation, spacy-3

I have a file that is annotated in IOB-format. I now appended each token of column one to a list of sentences, so that each sentence is one list of tokens. I then iterate over the list of tokens while iterating over the list of sentences. The code:

```
with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Spacy/Test/annotated_tuebadz_spacy.tsv', 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as tsvfile:
wrt = csv.writer(tsvfile, delimiter='\t')
nlp = spacy.load("/content/drive/MyDrive/Spacy/model/model-best")

for sent in sent_list:

    for token in sent:
        doc = nlp(token)
        if doc[0].ent_iob_ == "O":
            label = doc[0].ent_iob_ + doc[0].ent_type_
        else:
            label = doc[0].ent_iob_ + "-" + doc[0].ent_type_
        print(doc.text, label)
        wrt.writerow((doc.text, label))
```

where sent_list is the list of tokenized sentences where each sentence consists of tokens. [["I", "am", "a", "robot","."],["How", "are", you", "?"]]. I want to manually compare gold annotations in the original script so I want to stick to the tokenization style.

Now, my question: the results are much lower than the scores when using the evaluate script from spacy (which would not annotate the file itself). Is the problem, that it does not use context information? How can I improve the script? Are there any suggestions? Also other strategies would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not clear what's going on here. It sounds like you have an IOB file but spaCy can't convert it for some reason? So you're re-writing it into a different format for spaCy to convert, but you get lower scores than with `spacy evaluate`. But if you can't convert the file how are you evaluating with spaCy? What else are you evaluating it with? It would help if you could rewrite your question to explain what you're trying to do *first* and then touch on this file format thing.

Comment: yes, I already did that. But I want a file that contains all the predictions from my model. I converted my IOB-file, everything is fine, but I want to actually have all the predictions in such a form, that I can compare it with the original annotated IOB-test file. So can I write the predictions to json as well?

Comment: Thing is, that my training script only contained "B-PER", "I-PER", "B-ORG", "I-ORG", "B-LOC", "I-LOC", "B-GPE", "I-GPE", "B-OTH", "I-OTH", "O" and I fear, that it would not show me the correct scores.